# Why doesn't user search find "Warren P" when I search for "Warren P"?

Tags: support, user-search

I know this will sound quite localized and don't know if it's a duplicate but I feel it like a bug. Well, in short:

1. I've been searching for [a user whose display name is **Warren P**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84704/warren-p)
2. So I went to **[Users tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users)** and typed **warren p** knowing the search is case insensitive and here is the result:

[image]

So, how can I find this guy or the others using the similar nick pattern through the users tab search ?

Comment: I'm confused.  You got three results, and none of them are Warren P.  The user you're looking for doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That username is actually [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/84704/warren-p).  They definitely exist.

Comment: @Robert, forgot to mention, I haven't tried this for the others with the similar nick pattern...

Comment: Weirdly, [Warren B](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1144364/warren-b) shows up just fine in the search.  It's just [Warren P](http://stackoverflow.com/users/84704/warren-p) who isn't properly included.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Warren P has **two spaces** in his user name, between "Warren" and "P".

Comment: Is there any way to discover that?  It's certainly not displayed with two spaces.

Comment: @blahdiblah: Inspect the element containing his username. There's two spaces in the source. It's just your browser collapses them into one.

Comment: I see, so just on the profile page it's trimmed to only one space. Thanks! Then would be fine to trim these spaces between at registration (profile change) pages since it's quite confusing and I don't think someone would like to have display name with more than one space between.

Comment: @TLama feature-request?

Comment: Sounds like a neat way to hide from inquiring minds.