# Different interpretation of username with sequence of spaces

Tags: bug, design, bounties, display-names

I noticed that if the username contains a sequence of spaces then they squashed into a single space. For example [this user](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/212367/kto-to?tab=profile) name displayed as `Kto to` (single whitespace), but actually his name is `Kto  to` (double whitespaces). This is not an issue if in all situations the name displayed same. But the tooltip for the [awarded bounty](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/754177/176217) shows me a double space:

> [image: double space]

I think this should be fixed for consistency.

Comment: This can be also "fixed" by applying this request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144857/automatically-trim-more-than-one-space-between-display-name-words