# Search for users has a blind spot

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search, users

Trying to find myself on the [SO User page](https://stackoverflow.com/users) I run into weird results. My display name is "Erwin Brandstetter", obviously.

If I type `Erwin`, I find myself in the search results.
If I type `Branst`, I find myself in the search results.
If I type `Erwin B` or even `Erwin Brandstetter`, I am **not** found.

Tried the same with `Jon Skeet` or `Brad Larson` and others, no problem. Works either way.
Tried the same on a couple of SE sites. Same effects everywhere. Here on meta, too.

Seems broken to me?

Comment: Related: [Automatically trim more than one space between display name words](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144857)

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't user search find "Warren P" when I search for "Warren P"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144848)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've got two spaces in your username:

```
Erwin  Brandstetter
```

They're collapsed by your browser when displayed in many cases, but if you look at the source you can see the true value.

Searching for "Erwin`<space><space>`B" &c work as expected.

Comment: Nailed it. For others who want to test it: I fixed this now. But you can just change your display name and try. FWIW: I don't think the search engine should be stopped by white space ... still feels kind of buggy.